# Does Devel::Size treat shared references correctly?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get an idea of the memory consumption of a data structure, and am unsure if [`Devel::Size`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aSize) treats shared references correctly.

here's a little data structure to illustrate my point:

```
use Devel::Size qw(total_size);

my $shared_obj = Foo->new();
my @list = ();
for (1..10) {
  push @list, Bar->new({ foo => $shared_obj });
}
print "Memory usage: ", total_size(\@list), "\n";
```

Perl should (AFAIK) allocate memory for a single `Foo` object, and each `Bar` object will only need the memory required for the hash reference to `Foo`.

My impression is that `Devel::Size` doesn't add up the memory usage correctly: it adds 10x the size of `Foo`, rather than 10x the size of a hash ref and 1x the size of `Foo`.

Can anybody confirm this behaviour? Is `Devel::Size` wrong, or is my understanding of Perl memory allocation wrong? Also, is there a better module for profiling complex data structures?

Answer (score 1):

What I see is compatible with what I expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Foo;

use strict; use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = [ 1 .. 1_000 ];
    return bless $self => $class;
}

package Bar;

use strict; use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = shift;
    return bless $self => $class;
}

package main;

use strict; use warnings;

use Devel::Size qw(total_size);

my $shared_obj = Foo->new;

my @list = map Bar->new({foo => $shared_obj}), 1 .. 10;

print "Memory usage of \@list: ", total_size(\@list), "\n";
print "Memory usage of \$shared_obj: ", total_size([$shared_obj]), "\n";
```

Output:

```
Memory usage of @list: 22389
Memory usage of $shared_obj: 20196
```

Of course, I do not know the internals of the `Bar` and `Foo` objects and right now I only have `perl` `5.10.1` and [Devel::Size](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Devel%3a%3aSize) `0.71` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

See if using a scalar-ref and not the scalar itself when creating the new `Bar`s resolves this issue:

```
push @list, Bar->new({ foo => \$shared_obj });
```

Comment: I don't have `Devel::Size` installed on my setup now.. can't test this right now